# Use of CanCan to show part of view to user with a specific role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

```
Rails
CanCan Gem
```

In the views/books/index.html.slim, view, I have the following:

```
.form-horizontal-column.autowidth
  .form-group.wtht-label
    = button_to t('download_invoice'), acocunts_receivables_path, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

But, I only want this button/link to show, if the user's role is cfo

So, in models/ability.rb, I have:

```
if user.cfo?
  can :manage, Invoice
```

How do I extend the use of CanCan, to that part of the index view, so only users with cfo role, will see this button?

Comment: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/checking-abilities#checking-with-class

Comment: This is not about an entire controller action, it's about a part of a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put if statements in `haml`.

```
.form-horizontal-column.autowidth
  .form-group.wtht-label
    - if can? :manage, Invoice
      = button_to t('download_invoice'), acocunts_receivables_path, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: In this case, I have an AccountsReceivablesController, but no model. Can I define, in Ability.rb: can :download, AccountsReceivableController

Comment: Do `can :download, :accounts_receivable`